# Go XML error: invalid character entity

Tags: go

Go can't parse a correct xml file with declared entities, keep getting this error:

> error: XML syntax error on line 47: invalid character entity &n;

The line being `<pos>&n;</pos>` and the entity defined as `<!ENTITY n "noun (common) (futsuumeishi)">`

Here is the program in Go: http://play.golang.org/p/94_60srVne

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass entities in if you create a `Decoder` and mess with its `Entity` map. I suspect the package doesn't actually parse DTDs, just from poking around [xml.go](http://golang.org/src/encoding/xml/xml.go); I see a comment saying it accumulates entities for the caller, but nothing that itself sets entries in `d.Entity`.

(It would be tricky for `encoding/xml` to safely provide that, even, because there is a built-in *shared* HTML entity map. Updating it for one doc would affect parsing of others.)

There's a little more paperwork to create a Decoder with custom entities than there is for regular `xml.Unmarshal`, but not too much:

```
func main() {
    jmd := JMdict{}

    d := xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader([]byte(str)))
    d.Entity = map[string]string{
        "n": "(noun)",
    }
    err := d.Decode(&jmd)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(jmd)
}
```

Here's a [Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/C-9cGzYa4g) with the `Entity` trick and some output code to show the object as JSON.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is the "right" answer, but I believe, depending on what you are really trying to accomplish, a "quick" answer is to disable Strict.  e.g.:

```
d := xml.NewDecoder(os.Stdin)
d.Strict = false
```

Comment: See docs for Strict on https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Decoder